# How can I modify this Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell, text-parsing, filesplitting

I have a single text file that contains 60K+ lines in it.  Those 60K+ lines are actually around 50 or so programs written in Natural.
I need to break them apart into individual programs.  I have a script that works perfectly with a single flaw.  The naming of the output files.

Every program starts with "Module Name=", followed by the actual name of the program.  I need to split the programs and save them using the actual program names.

Using the example below, I would like to create two files called Program1.txt and Program2.txt each containing the lines belonging to them.  I have a script, also below, that separates the files correctly, but I am unable to discern the correct way to capture the Program name and use that as the name of the output file.

Example:

```
Module Name=Program1
....
....
....
END

Module Name=Program2
....
....
....
END
```

Code:

```
$InputFile = "C:\Natural.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$a = 1
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "Module Name=") {
        $OutputFile = "MySplittedFileNumber$a.txt"
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

Comment: I commend to your attention Microsoft Docs on [`-Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) and [`-Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin
I am attempting to alter the code using the -Split command.  I will post success or failure.
-Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch), which can read files line by line efficiently with `-File` and can match each line against [regex(es)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) with `-Regex`, and use a [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter) instance to write the output files efficiently:

```
$outStream = $null

switch -Regex -File C:\Natural.txt {
  '\bModule Name=(\w+)' {   # a module start line
    if ($outStream) { $outStream.Close() }
    $programName = $Matches[1] # Extract the program name.
    # Create a new output file.
    # Important: use a *full* path.
    $outStream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\$programName.txt"
    # Write the line at hand.
    $outStream.WriteLine($_)
  }
  default {                 # all other lines
    # Write the line at hand to the current output file.
    $outStream.WriteLine($_)    
  }
}
if ($outStream) { $outStream.Close() }
```

Note:

- The code assumes that the very first line in the input file is a `Module Name=...` line.
- The regex matching is case-*insensitive* by default, as PowerShell generally is; add `-CaseSensitive`, if needed.
- The [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) is used to extract the program name from the matching result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jeff!

Here is my solution using the Split Command

```
$InputFile = "C:\Temp\EMNCP\Natural.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)

$OPName = @()
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "Module Name=") {
        $OPName = $Line.Split("=")
        $FileName = $OPName[1].Trim()
        Write-Host "Found ... $FileName" -foregroundcolor green
        $OutputFile = "$FileName.txt"

    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

Comment: Nice; a few tips: `$OPName = @()` initializes `$OPName` as an _array_, even though you want to it to be a _string_, but you actually don't need to initialize it at all. (The only way to lock in a type would be to _type-constrain_ the assignment: `[string] $OPName = ''`)

Comment: It's better to close / dispose of the stream reader explicitly (`$Reader.Close()`).

Comment: While using `Add-Content` in a loop works, it is quite slow, because the output file must be opened and closed for every call; hence the use of a `[System.IO.StreamWriter]` in my solution.